# Two questions (Modifying Ticks and VectorGraphics)

Tags: graphics3d, ticks

Say

```
x0[u_, v_, a_, b_, c_] := a* Cos[u]*Sin[v]
y0[u_, v_, a_, b_, c_] := b* Sin[u]*Sin[v]
z0[u_, v_, a_, b_, c_] := c*Cos[v]
```

I take a parametric plot by

```
 ParametricPlot3D[{x0[u, v, 10, 3, 2], y0[u, v, 10, 3, 2], 
  z0[u, v, 10, 3, 2]}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, \[Pi]}, Mesh -> False, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[ColorData["Rainbow"][x]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, ImageSize -> 600, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {{-2, "-2"}, {-1, " "}, {0, " 0"}, {1, " "}, {2,
      "2"}}, {{-2, "-2"}, {-1, " "}, {0, " 0"}, {1, " "}, {2, "2"}}}]
```

[image]

First Question
How is it possible to modify the ticks in positions -1,1 (of y and z-axis) giving them the appearance of minor ticks?

Second Question
How I can export the graphic in full Vector Graphic format manageable from, e.g., InkScape?

Thanks and Happy new year!

Comment: the second part of your questions hasn't been answered but Inscape uses SVG or PDF right? The Export docs will have some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x0[u_, v_, a_, b_, c_] := a*Cos[u]*Sin[v]
y0[u_, v_, a_, b_, c_] := b*Sin[u]*Sin[v]
z0[u_, v_, a_, b_, c_] := c*Cos[v]    

mTick = {0, -0.0035};

ParametricPlot3D[{x0[u, v, 10, 3, 2], y0[u, v, 10, 3, 2],
z0[u, v, 10, 3, 2]}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, \[Pi]}, 
   Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[ColorData["Rainbow"][x]]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, ImageSize -> 600, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   Ticks -> {Automatic, {{-2, "-2"}, {-1, " ", #}, {0, " 0"}, {1, 
       " ", #}, {2, "2"}}, {{-2, "-2"}, {-1, " ", #}, {0, " 0"}, {1, 
       " ", #}, {2, "2"}}}] &@mTick
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
mt = {0, -0.0025};

ParametricPlot3D[
 {x0[u, v, 10, 3, 2], y0[u, v, 10, 3, 2], z0[u, v, 10, 3, 2]},
 {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, \[Pi]},
 Mesh -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#1] &),
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 ImageSize -> 600,
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {-2, {-1, , mt}, 0, {1, , mt}, 2}, {-2, {-1, , mt}, 0, {1, , mt}, 2}}]
```

[image]